# Strange compiler error: 'expectation' produces 'XCTestExpectation', not the expected contextual result type 'XCTestExpectation'

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I'm trying to test async code that will run multiple times and trying to create a separate expectation ahead of time for mocked user input. I'm trying to use a struct that will be in an array that can be then accessed both by the async function and the main test function.

The following code though produces a compile error that I've never seen before and it seems like google hasn't either

```
struct TestAsyncUserInput<T> {
    var value : T
    var expect : XCTestExpectation

    init (value : T) {
        self.value = value
        self.expect = expectation(description: "a random expectation")
    }
}
```

self.expect shows this compiler error: 
**'expectation' produces 'XCTestExpectation', not the expected contextual result type 'XCTestExpectation'**

I'm on Xcode 10 with Swift 4.2

While there are different ways around it, I'm more concerned about what is this compiler error and why is it happing?

UPDATE: Here's a screenshot of the error

[image: Compiler error screenshot]

And for good measure the definition of the expectation function

```
open func expectation(description: String) -> XCTestExpectation
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
struct TestAsyncUserInput<T> {
    var value : T
    var expect : XCTestExpectation

    init (value : T) {
        self.value = value
        self.expect = XCTestExpectation(description: "a random expectation")
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting. For the life of me I can't understand why this would work and my version doesn't, also see updated question. Any idea as to what the compiler error is?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the underlying error is that `expectation` is a member function of `XCTestCase`, and in the initializer of `TestAsyncUserInput`, there is no instance to call it on. The error message is really confusing, I agree.